# Should I include "--bootstrap" when launching plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spork

What is the difference between the following two statements?

1. $spork --bootstrap
2. $spork

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--bootstrap` argument will update your test helper file with the code to run when Spork is starting. If you are using rspec, then it will add the boilerplate code to initialize spork and rsepc in your rspec_helper.rb file.

You should only run `spork --bootstrap` once when you are setting up a new test framework. To run spork and your tests, you should just run `spork`.